# How to enter the email subject and the email core in the "commit -a"?

Tags: git

I'm Contributing in the development of an open source which use git as repository.

And after finishing my modification I make `git commit -a` in order to commit locally

And then I enter my comment in the comment field of `git commit -a` window

And then If I send the patch with `git send-email` I get the whole message in the subject of the email.

And I want to enter in the `git commit -a` window both the subject and the email core separetly

How to do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put a blank line between:

- the first line of your commit message, which will be used as the subject) and
- the rest of the commit message, which will be used as the body by [`git send-email`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-send-email).

Comment: See also http://tbaggery.com/2008/04/19/a-note-about-git-commit-messages.html for more details.